# Nightmare Testing click() selector

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I want to get a reference to a DOM element and click on it but I don't know how to spot it.
In DOM will be like:

```
$('.filter-buttons :nth-child(2)').get(0).click() , or using [0]instead of get(0)
```

But with Nightmare function click accepts only one parameter .click(selector)

```
.click('.filter-buttons :nth-child(2)')
```

. The question is that I don't know where to put the get(0). Any ideas?

Comment: .get(0).click() is dom click, not jquery click..

Comment: If you hurry and edit your question to make slightly more sense in a acceptable format -- your question might survive.

Answer (score 3):

As it has mentioned `.get(0)` lets you find a dom node and you are applying a dom `click` event. so i suggest you to use `document.querySelector()` method:

```
.click(document.querySelector('.filter-buttons :nth-child(2)'))
```

[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

This method just returns a single dom node. which exactly is your requirement.

from the docs:

> Returns the first element within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes|by first element in document markup and iterating through sequential nodes by order of amount of child nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors.
>
> #### Example
>
> In this example, the *first element in the document* with the class "myclass" is returned:
>
> var el = document.querySelector(".myclass");